# Returning Value in if else error

Tags: swift

I have a dateFormatted and I am getting the date from API. I have got the value let's say 28 from 28th April 2018. So, I have to add the beside this 28 in Swift? Do anyone know this?

Else what I am trying is to set the values as "th" or "st" according to dates. I know the logics. I am just stuck with this:

```
let dateText = dateFormatterPrint.string(from: date)

if(dateText >= 4 && dateText <= 20) {
    print("I am th")
}
```

Here it says, Binary operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type Int and String. I want to check for the value in this range?

Can anyone please help?

P.S. I got this and when printing I am getting values correctly, but when I return I get an error

```
if((count! >= 4 && count! <= 20) || (count! >= 24 && count! <= 30)){
    return textVal = "I am th"
} else if(count! == 1 || count! == 21 || count! == 31) {
    return textVal = "I am st"
} else if(count! == 2 || count! == 22) {
    return textVal = "I am nd"
} else if(count! == 3 || count! == 23) {
    return textVal = "I am rd"
} else {
    print("I am known")
}
```

Use of unresolved identifier 'textVal'

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because you cannot return a variable which has never been declared

I recommend to use a `switch` statement

```
var dateText = dateFormatterPrint.string(from: date)
switch (dateText) {
case "1", "21", "31": dateText.append("st")
case "2", "22": dateText.append("nd")
case "3","23": dateText.append("rd")
default: dateText.append("th")
}
print(dateText)
```

Comment: So, instead of print how can I return the value of dateText?

Comment: `return dateText`

Comment: LOL! Sir, I did that and it gives this error Unexpected non-void return value in void function

Comment: The error says that your function is declared without a return value. Add one (`-> String`)

Comment: Expected type before '->' Error

Comment: Please learn the basics. The return type has to be added at the end of the declaration line e.g. `func doSomething() -> String { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to format an "ordinal number". The best way to do that is to configure a `NumberFormatter` to use a `ordinal` number style:

```
let ordinalNumberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
ordinalNumberFormatter.numberStyle = .ordinal

// for example...
ordinalNumberFormatter.string(from: 22) // "22nd"
ordinalNumberFormatter.string(from: 28) // "28th"
ordinalNumberFormatter.string(from: 31) // "31st"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't compare a String and an Int

```
if(dateText >= "4" && dateText <= "20")
{
     print("I am th")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already solved it. Will keep your suggestion in mind as well.

Comment: Sorry, hit by mistake. I have a new question can you help?

Comment: This answer doesn't compare the values as numbers. For example: 15 is between 4 and 20 but "15" is not lexicographically after "4" (because "1" is lexicographically before "4")

Comment: What is your problem? Tell me

Comment: I got that sir, I have new question can you please check that

Comment: I have added the new problem in the main area, after P.S. please check that